# JSON object in AJAX 'post' request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, forms

I am trying to push a json object to the server:

```
[
    {
        name: "A",
        username: "A",
        password: "123456",
        email: "A@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        username: "B1",
        password: "123456",
        email: "B1@example.com"
    }
]

save.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(myNewData);
    var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request2.open("POST", "url", true);
    request2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request2.send(dataJson);

    request2.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
});
```

myNewData is an JavaScript object which I am stringifying before sending the data.

Is this the right format to send the data? For some reason it seems the values are not filled when doing it this way

Comment: If you're sending JSON, why do you set the content type to `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: You are right, I've updated it now to "application/json;charset=UTF-8" but it still gives me the {"response":"sccess","content":"please fill all values"}

Answer (score 2):

If the API really supports JSON parameters, you should set the correct `Content-type:`:

```
request2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

If it really wants URL-encoded parameters, you can't use `JSON.stringify()`. You need to iterate over the objects and turn them into URL-encoded parameters of the form `name=value`. To send arrays, use `[]` after the names.

```
var dataArray = [];
myNewData.forEach(obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => dataArray.push(encodeURIComponent(key + "[]") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]))));
request2.send(dataArray.join("&");
```

This is the format that PHP expects, for instance.